# How to get next coming date/time in sql

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am looking for a sql query to get datetime before the time of next prayer. For example 5 minutes before the time of next prayer.

```
ID , Prayer_ID, TIME
661,         1, 2016-10-01 04:57:00.000
662,         2, 2016-10-01 12:11:00.000
663,         3, 2016-10-01 15:34:00.000
664,         4, 2016-10-01 18:09:00.000
665,         5, 2016-10-01 19:39:00.000
666,         1, 2016-10-02 04:57:00.000
667,         2, 2016-10-02 12:10:00.000
668,         3, 2016-10-02 15:34:00.000
669,         4, 2016-10-02 18:08:00.000
670,         5, 2016-10-02 19:38:00.000
671,         1, 2016-10-03 04:57:00.000
672,         2, 2016-10-03 12:10:00.000
673,         3, 2016-10-03 15:33:00.000
674,         4, 2016-10-03 18:07:00.000
675,         5, 2016-10-03 19:37:00.000
```

Let us say that next prayer time is `2016-10-01 15:34:00.000`.My required output is `2016-10-01 15:29:00.000`. Output is the time exactly `5 minutes` before time of next prayer.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please, rephrase your question, as written now it is hard to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: You mean befor the time of next prayer by 5 mn ?

Comment: @Sami, Yes I mean before 5 min

Comment: Then you can use `datediff `

Comment: @Sami i am totally new in sql. could you please help me to write this query???

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data

Comment: Thanks everyone, i got it by this query,

`SELECT DATEADD(minute,-5,(select top 1 TIME from prayertimes where Time>sysdatetime())) AS TIME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can DateAdd -5 Minutes to the current prayer time.
for example:

```
Select *, DateAdd(Minute, -5, [Time]) As AlertTime
From MyTable
```

However, if you want alert for the next record while you are reading the current record, you can use the Lead function.

```
Select *, DateAdd(Minute, -5, 
 Lead([Time]) Over(order by ID)) As AlertTime
from myTable
```